# How to compare UIViewController in Swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, swift3, uinavigationcontroller

I am trying to compare to UIViewController in Swift 3 but there is some error

```
extension UINavigationController
{
    func myPopToViewController(viewController:UIViewController, animated:Bool) -> UIViewController? {
        var arrViewControllers:[UIViewController] = []

        arrViewControllers = self.viewControllers
        for vc:UIViewController in arrViewControllers {
            if(vc.isKind(of: viewController) ) // This Line gives me error
            {
                return (self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)?.last)!
            }

        }
        return nil
    }

}
```

> /Users/varunnaharia/Documents/Projects/appname/appname/Public/UINavigationController+Extra.swift:18:30: Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')

and if try to use

```
if(vc is viewController)
```

It gives

> /Users/varunnaharia/Documents/Projects/appname/appname/Public/UINavigationController+Extra.swift:18:22: Use of undeclared type 'viewController'

I am calling it through this

```
self.navigationController?.popOrPopToViewController(viewController: MyUIViewController(), animated: false)
```

Comment: if vc is arrViewControllers { } try this

Comment: please explain how it will work ? it is giving same error ...

Comment: Try `if (vc is UIViewController)`

Comment: if vc is UIViewController {
   //vc is of class type UIViewController
}

Comment: **Try This it will work for you**        `if(vc.isKind(of: viewController.classForCoder) )     
            {
                return (self.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)?.last)!
            }` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compare to a particular view controller you have to compare their refererences.

Try this...

```
if(vc === viewController) )
{
    return (self.navigationController?.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated)?.last)!
}
```

Answer (score 20):

```
for viewsController in arrViewControllers
{
    if(viewsController.isKind(of: YourControllerClassName.self)){
    }
}
```

Comment: exactly same error  `Users/varunnaharia/Documents/Projects/appname/appname/Public/UINavigationController+Extra.swift:18:30: Cannot convert value of type 'UIViewController' to expected argument type 'AnyClass' (aka 'AnyObject.Type')`

Answer (score 9):

**Swift 4**
Hope it will work for you

```
   extension UINavigationController {
  func myPopToViewController(viewController:UIViewController, animated:Bool) {
    var arrViewControllers:[UIViewController] = []
    arrViewControllers = self.viewControllers
    for vc:UIViewController in arrViewControllers {
      if(vc.isKind(of: viewController.classForCoder)){
         (self.popToViewController(vc, animated: animated))
      }
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 6):

In swift, we use `is` instead of `isKind(of:)`.

`is` is used to check the `type of the object`.

So you can use,

```
if(vc is UIViewController)
```

But I think here you are trying to `match the 2 references of UIViewController`.

So, you need to use `===` instead of `is`. This operator is used to match 2 references of same type.

```
if(vc === viewController)
```

Comment: Thanks for your explanation

Answer (score 0):

i just modify the answer of Mr. @BangOperator for move to particular View controller.

```
extension UINavigationController {

func popTo(controllerToPop:UIViewController)  {

    //1. get all View Controllers from Navigation Controller
    let controllersArray = self.viewControllers

    //2. check whether that view controller is exist in the Navigation Controller
    let objContain: Bool = controllersArray.contains(where: { $0 == controllerToPop })

    //3. if true then move to that particular controller
    if objContain {
        self.popToViewController(controllerToPop, animated: true)
    }
  }
}
```